# LSTM input and output gradient and gradient shape

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to understand LSTMs and backpropagation with LSTMs. I have a simple architecture.

```
def __init__(self, input_dim=100, hidden_dim=100, output_dim=216, num_layers=2):
    super(LSTMGenerator, self).__init__()
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.layer1 = nn.LSTM(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim, self.num_layers, bidirectional=False, dropout=0.5)
    self.out = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)
```

I'm using the pytorch register_backward_hook function. I'm trying to modify the gradient in the backward pass. Should I use grad_input or grad_output? Which gradient is being used to update the previous weights?

I printed out the gradient shapes. What do the values in grad_input and grad_output mean?

```
length of grad input  3
grad input 0 shape  torch.Size([216])
grad input 1 shape  torch.Size([128, 100])
grad input 2 shape  torch.Size([100, 216])

length of grad output  1
grad ouput 0 shape  torch.Size([128, 216])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Grad_in: gradient of model output wrt. layer output

Grad_out: Grad_in * (gradient of layer output wrt. layer input)

(wrt= with respect to)

> Because backward pass runs from back to the start, it's parameter
> order should be reversed compared to the forward pass. Therefore, to
> be it clearer, I'll use a different naming convention below. For
> forward pass, previous layer of layer 2 is layer1; for backward pass,
> previous layer of layer 2 is layer 3.

Comment: for backward pass, previous layer of layer 2 is layer 3 and next layer is layer 1. In the backward pass, is grad_in the gradient of model output wrt. layer 2 output? And this is input to layer 1?

Comment: Yeah. Can you also share what are you trying to do in this project ? I am curious why would you interfere with gradients.